# Proving inequality $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c} \geq 4$

Tags: inequality, radicals, substitution, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, uvw

I started to study inequalities - I try to solve a lot of inequlites and read interesting .solutions . I have a good pdf, you can view from [here](https://web.williams.edu/go/math/sjmiller/public_html/161/articles/Riasat_BasicsOlympiadInequalities.pdf) . The inequality which I tried to solve and I didn't manage to find a solution can be found in that pdf but I will write here to be more explicitly.

> **Exercise 1.3.4(a)** Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers. Prove that
> $$\displaystyle \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c} \geq 4.$$
>
> **(b)** For real numbers $a,b,c \gt0$ and $n \leq3$ prove that:
> $$\displaystyle \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+n\left(\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c} \right)\geq 3+n.$$

Comment: Please avoid using `$$__$$` in the title.

Answer (score 18):

Write $$\frac ab+\frac ab+\frac bc\geq \frac{3a}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}$$ by AM-GM.

You get $$\operatorname{LHS} \geq \frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}+n\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\right).$$

Set $$z:=\frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}$$ and then notice that for $n\leq 3$, $$z+\frac{3n}{z}\geq 3+n.$$  Indeed the minimum is reached for $z=\sqrt{3n}\leq 3$; since $z\geq 3$, the minimum is reached in fact for $z=3$.

Comment: How did you prove that $z+3n/z \ge 3+n$ for $n\le 3?$

Answer (score 3):

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{ab}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+ac+bc}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+ac+bc}+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\geq4.$$
Now, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Hence, our inequality it's $f(v^2)\geq0,$ where $f$ decreases, which says that it's enough to prove the last inequality for a maximal value of $v^2$, which happens for equality case of two variables.

Since the last inequality is homogeneous, we can assume $b=c=1$. Also, let $a=x^3$.

Id est, we need to prove that
$$\frac{(x^3+2)^2}{2x^3+1}+\frac{3x}{x^3+2}\geq4$$ or
$$(x-1)^2(x^6+2x^5+3x^4+2x^3+x^2+6x+3)\geq0.$$ 
Done!

The following inequality is also true.

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positives. Prove that:
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{24\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\geq11.$$

Comment: what is C-S? Can you explain

Comment: It's Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: For all reals $a_i$ and positives $b_i$ we have: $\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}+...+\frac{a_n^2}{b_n}\geq\frac{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2}{b_1+b_2+...+b_n}.$

Comment: oh thanks, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

Following above motivations and applying AM-GM three times:
\begin{align}
&\frac13\left(\frac ab+\frac ab+\frac bc\right)+\frac13\left(\frac bc+\frac bc+\frac ca\right)+\frac13\left(\frac ca+\frac ca+\frac ab\right)+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\\
&\ge \frac{a}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\\
&=\frac{a+b+c}{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}+\frac{a+b+c}{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}+\frac{a+b+c}{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\\
&\ge4\left(\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}\right)^2\right)^\frac14\\
&\ge4.
\end{align}