# Problem in Arithmetic Mean - Geometric Mean inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let a,b,c be positive real numbers, prove that 
$$ \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a}  + \frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c} \geq 4$$

I am suppose to use AM-GM inequality, I tried 
$$  \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a}  \geq 3 $$  and
$$ a + b + c\geq 3 \sqrt[3]{abc} $$ implying $$ \frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c} \leq 1 $$ Now adding the two inequality could give me the desired result but the problem I face is with second inequality sign(it's less than or equal to 1 rather than greater

Comment: @mechanodroid There is a certain irony in that the (wrongly) accepted answer [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189143/proving-inequality-fracab-fracbc-fracca-frac3-sqrt3abca) makes exactly the error that the OP (correctly) caught in their question here.

Comment: @Ehit Karim  $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a}  + \frac{24\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c} \geq 11$ is also true.

Answer (score 1):

I will go the standard way. Let us introduce $A,B,C>0$ with
$$
a=A^3\ ,\
b=B^3\ ,\
c=C^3\ .
$$
Then we have to show
$$
\frac{A^3}{B^3}+
\frac{B^3}{C^3}+
\frac{C^3}{A^3}+
\frac{3ABC}{A^3+B^3+C^3}
-4\ge 0
\ .
$$
We multiply with $A^3B^3C^3(A^3+B^3+C^3)$, and have to show equivalently:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&A^9C^3+B^9A^3+C^9B^3\\
&\qquad+A^6B^6+B^6C^6+C^6A^6\\
&\qquad\qquad+3A^4B^4C^4\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ge 3A^6B^3C^3 + 3A^3B^6C^3 +3A^3B^3C^6 \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Let us see how to dominate the terms on the R.H.S of $\ge $ with the ones on the $L.H.S$. Consider first $3A^6B^3C^3$. The degree is $(6,3,3)$.
We consider it in the plane $X+Y+Z=12$, and search for a triangle using the weights

- $(9,0,3)$, $(3,9,0)$, $(0,3,9)$,
- $(6,6,0)$, $(6,0,6)$, $(0,6,6)$,
- $(4,4,4)$,

in the same plane, which contains $(6,3,3)$ in its interior.
We do so, since we want to apply the inequality
$$
a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+\dots\ge x_1^{a_1}\cdot x_2^{a_2}\cdot x_3^{a_3}\cdot\dots
\ ,
$$
where $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ are positive weights.

- From $\frac 47(9,0,3)+\frac 27(3,9,0)+\frac 17(0,3,9)=(6,3,3)$ we obtain the inequality:
  $$
  \frac 47A^9C^3 + 
  \frac 27A^3B^9 + 
  \frac 17B^3C^9 \ge 
  (A^9C^3)^{4/7}\cdot
  (A^3B^9)^{2/7}\cdot
  (B^3C^9)^{1/7}
  =
  A^6B^3C^3\ .
  $$
- Cyclically doing this, we can "cover" (dominate) once the sum
  $A^6B^3C^3 + A^3B^6C^3 +A^3B^3C^6 $.
- But the problem with this domination is that we have not used our weakest term, the one with $(4,4,4)$, but instead we have lost the strongest. So we have to combine. A general combination would be of the shape:
  $$
  \left(\frac 47-\frac r3\right)
  (9,0,3)
  +
  \left(\frac 27-\frac r3\right)
  (3,9,0)
  +
  \left(\frac 17-\frac r3\right)
  (0,3,9)
  +r(4,4,4)
  =(6,3,3) \ .
  $$
  Then best value we can use for $r$ is $r=\frac 37$.
  This gives
  $$
  \frac 37
  (9,0,3)
  +
  \frac 17
  (3,9,0)
  +
  \frac 37(4,4,4)
  =(6,3,3) \ .
  $$
- This gives then an inequality of the same shape as above, we multiply it with $\frac 74$ to get:
  $$
  \frac 34A^9C^3 + 
  \frac 14A^3B^9 + 
  \frac 34A^4B^4C^4 \ge
  \frac 74A^6B^3C^3\ .
  $$
- Cyclically doing this, we can "cover" (dominate) $7/4$ of the sum
  $A^6B^3C^3 + A^3B^6C^3 +A^3B^3C^6 $.
- For the rest, we know what we still have to show, this is
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  &A^6B^6+B^6C^6+C^6A^6\\
  &\qquad+\frac34A^4B^4C^4\\
  &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ge \frac 54(A^6B^3C^3 + A^3B^6C^3 +A^3B^3C^6) \ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- We multiply with $\frac 45$, have to show equivalently
  $$
  \frac 45A^6B^6+\frac 45B^6C^6+\frac 45C^6A^6+\frac35A^4B^4C^4
  \ge 
  A^6B^3C^3 + A^3B^6C^3 +A^3B^3C^6\ .
  $$
- This follows from
  $$
  \frac 25A^6B^6+\frac 25A^6C^6+\frac15A^4B^4C^4
  \ge 
  A^6B^3C^3\ ,
  $$

(after we cycle and add). The last inequality corresponds to
$$
\frac 25(6,6,0)+\frac 25(6,0,6)+\frac 15(4,4,4)=(6,3,3)\ .
$$

---

Note: This proof can be now rewritten to fit in a few lines, however, i prefer to give it all... There was no point where i did something unnatural, so this is a natural solution.