# Prove that for $n\leq 3$, $z+\frac{3n}{z}\geq 3+n.$

Tags: inequality

> Let $$z:=\frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}.$$  Prove that for $n\leq 3$, $$z+\frac{3n}{z}\geq 3+n.$$

This was written here and I couldn't understand it. [Proving inequality $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{3\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c} \geq 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189143/proving-inequality-fracab-fracbc-fracca-frac3-sqrt3abca)

Can anyone explain?

Comment: If $z>0$
$z+\frac{3n}{z}\ge 3+n \implies z^2-(3+n)z+3n \ge 0$
As $\Delta= (3+n)^2-12n=(n-3)^2 \le 0 \implies n=3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will use the assumptions from your linked post that $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^+$. We have by AM-GM that
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq\sqrt[3]{abc}$$
$$\frac{a+b+c}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}\geq 3$$
$$z\geq 3$$

Note that we have
$$z+\frac{3n}{z}\geq 3+n$$
$$\iff z-3\geq \frac{z-3}{z}n$$
$$\iff \frac{(z-3)(z-n)}{z}\geq 0$$
We can easily see that $z-3$, $z-n$, and $z$ will all be nonnegative. Hence it follows that the entire expression will be nonnegative.